# Set button coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views

I have this code in coffeescript and i can't modify it:

```
events: 
 "click #chat-btn": "_toggleChat"

render: ->
   compiledTemplate = _.template(sessionNavbarTemplate)
   @$el.html compiledTemplate
   @_setToggleButtonStatus()

initialize: ->
  @$parentEl = null

_setToggleButtonsStatus: ->    
  $("#chat-btn", @$el).toggleClass "active", @$parentEl.hasClass("chat-on")
```

I try to insert the last line of code in the initialize section but the program crash.
I have an interface where if i click a button i have the chat. I don't know coffeescript very well and i would the chat appear without pressing the button. How can i do?

Comment: I cut the code for publish this part of code. I would modify only the part of chat button.

Comment: Sorry, i have modified the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the view:

```
events: 
 "click #chat-btn": "_toggleChat"
```

essentially binds a click handler to `#chat-btn`; the binding is actually done through event delegation but that's not important here. If you want to simulate someone clicking on `#chat-btn` then just call [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click) on it:

```
$('#chat-btn').click()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pX6QZ/

Keep in mind that `#chat-btn` won't necessarily be in the DOM until after that view has rendered.

Comment: So, i must insert '$('#chat-btn').click()' after ' "click #chat-btn": "_toggleChat"'

Comment: And if i would see the chat without the botton, how can i do?

Comment: You'd just call `$('#chat-btn').click()` where ever you wanted to open the chat. And for "see the chat without the button", you probably can't as the view would presumably create the button; unless you want to remove the button by hand after rendering the view and then call `view._toggleChat()` by hand.